# Triggoring Form focus with logic to another field

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using React Hook Forms in the react. And they are pretty easy to handle, And I understand all the logic behind them.

But using just Javascript and HTML how can I achieve that?
I have repeated forms where users can add numbers and prices. There can be multiple Number and Price fields.
If the user entered the number and missed the price then the form should give an error on onSubmit and focus on that specific input.

If the user doesn't enter the number and price then the form should submit without error.

I tried something where I can invoke `alert()` but how I can replicate something advanced like focusing forms with forms feedback.

Current Apprach

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function validateForm() {
        let number = document.forms["myForm"]["fnumber"].value;
        let price = document.forms["myForm"]["fprice"].value;
        if (number.length > 1 && price === '') {
          alert("Price cannot be empty");
        } else if (number.length > 1 && price.lenght > 1) {
          alert("Form Submited (with number and price) ");
        } else {
          alert("Form Submited Empty");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>JavaScript Validation For HTML</h2>
    <p>Form can submit number and price empty</p>
    <p>
      Form shouldnt submit number if is price empty and invoke focus on that
      specific input
    </p>
    <p>How to handle multiple forms</p>
    <form
      name="myForm"
      onsubmit="return validateForm()"
      action="/"
      method="GET"
    >
     <div>Number: <input type="text" name="fnumber" /> Price:
      <input type="text" name="fprice" /></div>
      <div>Number2: <input type="text" name="fnumber2" /> Price2:
      <input type="text" name="fprice2" /></div>
      
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also trying the approach as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73243063/how-to-disable-a-button-until-all-the-input-fields-are-filled-using-only-javascr/73243157#73243157)

As suggested by @zer00ne
But can't replicate it. This Update code is in the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-xpvr9r?file=/index.html)

Comment: Add the `required` attribute to the `<input>`s you want filled in before submitting the `<form>`.

Comment: Suppose there are 10 repeated inputs for numbers and prices , if user enters 1, number and 1 price and others are empty then submit button should work

Comment: Why this question marked closed. this was not about just adding required into fields

Comment: *"If the user entered the number and missed the price then the form should give an error on onSubmit and focus on that specific input."* You put required on the `<input>` with the price. There was no mention about 10 `<input>` and any set of two is permitted (which is actually only one required in the question).

Comment: You bind the input event to `<form>` and once there is a set of `<input>` that have text, you remove the `required` attributes from all of them.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73243157/2813224). But instead of a button with `disabled` it's `<input>` with `required`. If you can't figure it out just repost the question and I'll answer it, leave a comment here and I'll respond. Try **Example B** it looks like you are familiar with the HTMLForm interface syntax.

Comment: @zer00ne Please see the edited question.

Comment: I saw but I can't answer it, it's closed. The requirements from that question differ from this question. The old requirements are more logical than the newer requirements. The new requirement would follow this logic: 1. button starts enabled 2. as soon as the "number" input has text, the button is disabled... 3. ...unless the "price" input has text. So what happens if there's no text in "number" and there's text in the "price" input? Sending a blank form makes no sense step 1. shouldn't exist it seems pointless. Have you looked at [**Example B**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73243157/2813224)?

Comment: Can u give me a little idea, of how I can change it to focus instead of alert?

Comment: `document.getElementById('fprice2').focus();`

Comment: Thanks, zer00ne. Now I can do something with that.

Comment: You could run a loop for a number of input fields and can check the price is filled where the number is filled. 

Complete Solution for you here. https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-dskqyw?file=/index.html

Comment: Thanks, Faisal. that was it.